# Vue + typescript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript

Всем привет,нужна помощь,как лучше всего добавить typescript в существующий проект на vue с vuex и т.д? В интернете нормального объяснения так и не нашел

Comment: Если вам typescript нужен только для строгой типизации, то возможно лучшим решением будет использовать flow js,  чтобы не переписывать весь проект на typescript. 
https://flow.org

Comment: вот подробная статья https://johnpapa.net/vue-typescript/ от **John Papa**

Answer (score 1):

При создании проекта через vue-cli 3, предлагается выбор typescript. Лучше всего использовать typescript в виде class-based, т.е. через аннотации. Вот неплохая статья https://webformyself.com/vue-js-typescript-prostaya-rabota-v-redaktore, но для vuex, рекомендую использовать вот эту библиотеку https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators.

Answer (score 0):

Делал проект с этого примера: [TypeScript-Vue-Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter)
, может быть пригодится